# What is aMule server, and why is my TP-Link Router configured to use it?

Tags: router

So I was scrolling through the settings of my new TP-Link Archer C7 router when I stumbled upon this setting called "Offline Downloads".

Giving the description:
***If the source is a URL for aMule, click Advanced in the Offline Download section and specify the aMule server IP address and port number, and then click Save.***

And to my surprise, some public IP and Port number seems to already be filled in, without any option to change/disable it without using this feature.

The IP itself seems to be hard-coded into the firmware since the same IP appears in the user guide for the C7 router. I have not configured this field myself.

[image]

User guide for reference: https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/archer-a7&c7_v5/usb-settings-us-4.0#ug-sub-title-3 (Scroll all the way to the bottom).

Is this weird or am I just being paranoid?

I have no intention of using this feature and have left the Offline Downloads setting disabled, but I find it kind of sketchy for TP-Link to hard-code this IP into the firmware.

I also consider myself reasonably tech-savy but I have never ever heard about ***aMule*** before.
I also contacted the TP-Link support for answers but was basically left with "No, there is no security implications of leavning this as is." And "It has to do with aMule or something" and that is a direct quote.
Oh, they also sent me a wikipedia article about aMule, which made me even more confused.

So, could you guys help me out and perhaps ease my mind about this?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
My question is simply: Is it safe to leave this as is? I'm not sure if leaving this IP here could potentially lead to a malicious packages being transferred to my router.

Comment: It is safe. It does not do anything unless the feature is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

[eMule](https://www.emule-project.net/home/perl/general.cgi?l=1) is a Peer-to-Peer file sharing client. Many new routers ship with similar downloading applications.

Comment: Thank you Dan! I still find it odd that this IP would be preconfigured on my router, and I'm not sure if this could lead to possible malware/viruses being transferred to my router/home network.

Comment: The real issue with is having a port open to the internet that points to the application. Do what you can to close the port or disable the application if you don't plan on using it. If anyone on the internet can access it and there are any vulnerabilities in it, that could easily lead to someone gaining remote access to your router. Bad times ensue.